# How symmetric Halbach array can produce asymmetric magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, halbach-array

I don't understand. If I look at a picture of [Halbach array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array)

[image]

I see it is apparently symmetric. At least both pairs of opposite sides are.

Then how can it have "weak" and "strong" opposite sides?

Comment: This iamge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbach_array#/media/File:Fridge_Magnet_Halbach.svg is all you need to understand, how it works.

Comment: So, parts should not be squared bu triangled?